# Abelian categories have become the language of homological algebra. Why haven't Zariski categories become the language of commutative algebra?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I'm not seeing much mention of Zariski categories in the literature. There is no article on Zariski categories in nLab, which would seem to be an obvious place to have such an article. What has happened to Diers' project of moving the language of commutative algebra towards Zariski categories analogously to the way that the language of homological algebra has moved towards Abelian categories? Did this undertaking not bear fruit?

Comment: The end of the Math Review of Diers' book "Categories commutative algebras" addresses your question quite well: *Readers who prefer more concrete mathematics will probably translate as they go along to see "what's really going on''; they may have a variety of opinions as to how valid is the exercise of adding on what they may regard as categorical superstructure.  I feel that there is a debate to be joined here as to the extent and nature of the use of abstraction in mathematics.* The concept of abelian category clarified central issues in homological algebra, yielding important new theorems.

Comment: Where is suggested reading for this? I've never heard of this. Ever.

Comment: Yves Diers wrote a book: "Categories of Commutative Algebras" (1992). He defines Zariski categories there, in an attempt to describe categories that behave like commutative algebras do, in an attempt to solve commutative algebra problems using category theory, and to generalize the subject in a way similar to the way that abelian categories have generalized the theory of abelian groups, R-modules, sheaves, homological algebra, etc.

Comment: The obvious answer is: No important result (outside of Zariski categories) has been proven by using Zariski categories so far. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)